# Use parameters for serializing graphql response

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am using GraphQl with Apollo.

So let's say I have a query looking like this:

```
holidays(startDate, endDate, newDate) {
    price
    food
  }
```

I am trying to serialize the response using the parameter passed to the query for caching purposes, hoping to get a response looking something like:

```
"data": {
    `${newDate}`: {
      "price": 23,
      "food":['bananas']
    }
 }
```

or

```
  "data": {
    "holidays": {
      `${newDate}`: {
         "price": 23,
         "food":['bananas']
       }
    }
  }
```

Any idea how to go about it? Basically, using the parameter to the query to serialize the response.

Comment: ??? apollo already caches it (normalizing cache built in) ... under key like `'query human(id: "1000")'`... but not in human/by type - id missing in response, ... read docs?

Comment: I am sorry, I gave the wrong example. the parameter is not part of the type. I have updated my question.

Comment: no, you can't use dynamic keys [at any depth] ... you don't get repsponse like that from [any] graphql server ... you can try to use custom [holidays array type handler/modifier] cache functions to save individual entries [from array] in custom way/available for querying by date ... but it looks like you're at the begining of using graphql/apollo